# How to parse SPARQL results?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, rdf, sparql, text-parsing

I am using [Twinkle](http://www.ldodds.com/projects/twinkle/) (A SPARQL Query Tool). I did a SPARQL over a RDF file, and got a results file like below. Since it doesn't seems a typical file format like CSV, do you know a library to parse this format? Any programming language is fine.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| name                                                              |
=====================================================================
| "Egypt"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>                |
| "Iraq"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>                 |
| "Jordan"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>               |
| "Kuwait"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>               |
| "Libya"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>                |
| "Mauritania"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>           |
| "Somalia"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>              |
| "Sudan"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>                |
| "Syrian Arab Republic"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> |
| "Tunisia"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>              |
| "United Arab Emirates"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> |
| "Yemen"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not any standard format, so you'd have to write a parser for that by hand; it looks like the default CLI output of a query command for a database (which one I wonder?).

The query command from the CLI probably has the option to provide standard SPARQL results formats, such as SPARQL/XML or SPARQL/JSON, which you can use any standard RDF library, such as [Jena](http://jena.apache.org) or [Sesame](http://openrdf.org) if you are working in Java, to parse the results in that format.  That is the best way to accomplish what you're attempting.

Generally, you should not interface programmatically with CLI output and instead use API's provided with the database.

Comment: the database is the geopolitical FAO ontology: http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/geoinfo/en/ . I don't know if they provide an API outside their web service API, which I don't want to use. The SPARQL GUI I'm using doesn't seem to provie a way to specify an output format parameter.

Comment: @Michael Twinkle uses ARQ under the hood so that's just the text format output from ARQ

Answer (score 2):

That looks like it could be Jena output.

The ResultSetFormatter class contains ways to format results in all the standard formats (XML, JSON, TSV, CSV) as well as this display format in text.

> ResultsetFormatter.outputAsXML
>
> ResultsetFormatter.outputAsJSON
>
> ResultsetFormatter.outputAsTSV
>
> ResultsetFormatter.outputAsCSV

The text format is not for parsing - more for simple display and debugging.

The command line has args to set the results format e.g. `--results json`

And the query form in Fuseki allows you to choose the output format.

Comment: Yep, Twinkle is one of Leigh's old tools and it's based on ARQ (albeit something like 2.6.4!)

Answer (score 0):

The format you see is a  [Typed RDF literal](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-rdf-concepts-20040210/#dfn-literal). The URI http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string is a [XSD type  "string"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#string) saying that your value is just a "string" (it could be an "int", etc...). If you just want the value, you can omit the URI after "^^" or use the [STR](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) function in your SPARQL query.

Comment: He's not asking what those literals mean, he's asking about how to parse that tabular format.

Comment: Pierre, the only way I found to use the STR() function is inside the WHERE clause, like "FILTER regex(str(?name), "United*")". Do you know if it's possible to actually extract the country name string with the STR() function?